# ggplot2 - The unit of size

Tags: r, ggplot2

A quick question that I can't find answer on the web (or Wickham's book):

What is the unit of the size argument in `ggplot2`? For example, `geom_text(size = 10)` -- `10` in what units?

The same question applies to default unit in `ggsave(height = 10, width = 10)`.

Comment: Until now, I believed the text size was in points (as in font sizes). Is this still true, albeit a simplified explanation?
In `pdf()`, `postscript()` etc., the `height` and `width` are given in inches, so would it be wrong to assume that `ggsave` also uses inches?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a “unit of the size argument in `ggplot2`” because there is more than one `size` argument. The `size` argument to `geom_text()` does something very different from the `size` argument to `element_text()`, and I have no idea how to reconcile the two or why they would be different.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The answer is : The unit is the points. It is the unit of fontsize in the `grid` package. In `?unit`, we find the following definition

```
"points" Points. There are 72.27 points per inch.
```

(but note the closely related "bigpts" `Big Points. 72 bp = 1 in.`)

Internally `ggplot2` will multiply the font size by a magic number `ggplot2:::.pt`, defined as **1/0.352777778**.

Here a demonstration, I create a letter using grid and ggplot2 with same size:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1,y=1,label=c('A'))) +
  geom_text(aes(x,y,label=label),size=100)
## I divide by the magic number to get the same size.
grid.text('A',gp=gpar(fontsize=100/0.352777778,col='red'))
```

[image]

*Addendum* Thanks to @baptiste

The "magic number"(*defined in aaa-constants.r as .pt <- 1 / 0.352777778*) is really just the conversion factor between "points" and "mm", that is `1/72 * 25.4 = 0.352777778`. Unfortunately, `grid` makes the subtle distinction between "pts" and "bigpts", which explains why `convertUnit(unit(1, "pt"), "mm", valueOnly=TRUE)` gives the slightly different value of `0.3514598`.

Comment: Nice answer. It is likely my ignorance of why this was done, but isn't this a bit hackish?

Comment: So what is a good practice while specifying the size? Too often I find myself wondering which size is appropriate, which is the original motivation of my question. Thanks again for the nice demo!

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. hackish do you talk about the division of the magic number? it looks like a dirty implementation but I don't think so it is a compromise.Note that :1-) There isn't a lot of constants in ggplot2, 2-)when you deal with text you are obliged to do something like this , (see also strheight() and strWidth() in basic plot)... But I think we will get better explanations from ggplot2 proficients...

Comment: @Anh Personally I would try to test.Maybe You can do a dichotomous to choose faster...

Comment: Hmm I was hoping that there is something more than trial and error because this consumes quite a bit of my time as I wrap up my plots. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: The magic number used throughout ggplot2 is `fontsize = size * ggplot2:::.pt`, which is defined in `aaa-constants.r` as `.pt <- 1 / 0.352777778`

Comment: and for the sake of clarity, one may note that `1/72 * 25.4 = 0.352777778`, that is point -> inch -> mm. Grid converts points to mm slightly differently, presumably because the definition of points is sometimes argued to be device-specific.

Comment: @baptiste feel free to add this to the answer. I can't formulate it better.

Comment: I've edited, but it's a bit messy. In fact, one could argue that ggplot2 is using a slightly incorrect factor.

Comment: isn't the unit in ggplot2 aes() mm? see user1609452's answer below. the actual font size in points in your answer should be 100/0.35277=283.465

Comment: A rewrite of this answer would be appreciated. The unit of size in ggplot2 is mm, not pt, and I've just redefined .pt as 72 / 25.4 to hopefully make that more clear in the code

Comment: And I've now changed it to 72.27 / 25.4 since as pointed out in the comments, grid uses printers' pointers, not Adobe/big points.

Comment: Is this 72 defined by dpi? If I want to save the plot as a png with different resolutions, will I get different results? Or, do I need to adjust all the size = ***? It seems to be the case.

Comment: Follow-up question: Where can I vent my frustration due to ggplot2 and LaTeX not using the same definition for "pt"? 10pt in ggplot2 and 10pt in LaTeX side-by-side is noticeable.

Comment: “The unit is the points. It is the unit of fontsize in the grid package.” These two sentences are contradictory. Are points the units for `size` in a `geom`, or are points the unit for `fontsize` in `grid`? If points are the units for `size` in a `geom` and if `ggplot2` “will multiply the font size by a magic number” before passing it to `grid`, then points are NOT the unit of `fontsize` in `grid`.

Answer (score 8):

The 'ggplot2' package, like 'lattice' before it, is built on the `grid` package. You can get the available units at:

```
?grid::unit
?grid::convertX
?grid::convertY

grid::convertX(grid::unit(72.27, "points"), "inches")
```

(I use the formalism `pkg::func` because in most cases `grid` is loaded a a NAMESPACE but not attached when either `lattice` or `ggplot2 are loaded.)

I earlier posted a comment that I later deleted saying that `size` was in points. I did so after seeing that the size of the text with `size=10` was roughly 10 mm. The "magic" number mentioned by agstudy is in fact within 1% of:

```
as.numeric(grid::convertX(grid::unit(1, "points"), "mm"))
#[1] 0.3514598
0.352777778/.Last.value
#[1] 1.00375
```

Comment: I had thought units of size were in mm http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2-dev/tree/browse_frm/thread/37ba1aaaf8e22b38/a2c142da58418570?hide_quotes=no&pli=1 I wonder why the magic number is not 0.3514598.

Comment: Perhaps it's that size ratio on hadley's device. I'm working on a six year-old Mac.

Comment: I'd repeat my question for the poster above: so given this information, do you recommend any good practice regarding specifying size in points? I often find myself wasting time with trial and error.

Comment: I guess if you want to specify points multiply the points you want by the magic number.

Answer (score 4):

From `?aes_linetype_size_shape`

```
# Size examples
# Should be specified with a numerical value (in millimetres),
# or from a variable source
```

`height` and `width` in ggsave relate to `par("din")` from `?par`

> ```
> din
>
>   R.O.; the device dimensions, (width, height), in inches. See also dev.size,
>   which is updated immediately when an on-screen device windows is re-sized.
> ```

So I guess `size` in `aes` is in millimetres and `ggsave` `height` and `width` are in inches.