# ggplot2 specify point size in axis units

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to do a plot with large points inside a rectangle from a simple dataset. There are potentially multiple results that I want to display in different facets. The problem is that the size of the rectangle (using `geom_rect`) is defined in axis units while the `size` argument of `geom_point` is in some other units. Thus, the relative size of the points wrt the rectangle changes depending on the number of facets:

```
data<-data.frame(y=1:3,
                 facet=factor(1:3),
                 x=rep(1,3))

testplot<-function(data){
  p<-ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y,color=y))
  p<-p+facet_grid(.~facet)
  p<-p+scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,1.5))
  p<-p+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.5,3.5))
  p<-p+geom_rect(xmin=0.85,xmax=1.15,ymin=0.74,ymax=3.25)
  p<-p+geom_point(size=50)
  return(p)
}

p1<-testplot(subset(data,facet=="1"))
p2<-testplot(data)
```

My question is, if I can scale the absolute point size in axis units, so that the relative size of points and the rectangle is identical for p1 and p2, independent of the number of facets in the graph.

Comment: [**This Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size) doesn't answer your question, but may still be relevant reading for your thoughts on "`geom_point` in some other units".

Comment: [**Possibly relevant as well?**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/gl97TrK31tE). E.g. the answer of @baptise: "If you want to add a circle in cartesian coordinates indicating a distance from a centre, then `geom_point()` is not the appropriate `geom` for this task. You should probably use `geom_polygon` instead and construct a circle manually with many vertices. That way, it will respect the coordinates, even after munching."

Answer (score 2):

[ggforce](/questions/tagged/ggforce) makes this fairly straight forward, the radius `r` is scaled relative to the coordinate scales (therefore important to use `coord_fixed()` if you want circles).

**Examples**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

##sample data frame
grid_df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = rep(1,5), r = seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1), fill = letters[1:5])
```

*with empty circles*

```
ggplot() + 
geom_circle(data = grid_df, mapping = aes(x0 = x,  y0 = y, r = r)) + 
coord_fixed()
```

[image]

*with filled circles and "fixed" fill (outside of `aes`)*

```
ggplot() + 
geom_circle(data = grid_df, mapping = aes(x0 = x,  y0 = y, r = r), fill = 'black') + 
coord_fixed()
```

[image]

*with filled circles and fill based on variable (inside of `aes`)*

```
ggplot() + 
geom_circle(data = grid_df, mapping = aes(x0 = x,  y0 = y, r = r, fill = fill)) + 
coord_fixed()
```

[image]