# ggplot geom_text font size control

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to change the font to 10 for the labels of my bar plot in `ggplot2` by doing something like this:

```
ggplot(data=file,aes(x=V1,y=V3,fill=V2)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge",colour="white") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=V2),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
                                                 hjust=1.5,colour="white") +
    theme_bw()+theme(element_text(size=10))

ggsave(filename="barplot.pdf",width=4,height=4)
```

but the resulting image has super big font size for the bar plot labels.

Then I thought of modifying in `geom_text()` with this:

```
geom_text(size=10,aes(label=V2),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
                                                   hjust=1.5,colour="white")
```

The label font is even bigger...

I can change the size within `geom_text` to something like 3 and now it looks like font 10, similar to the axis labels.

I'm wondering what's going on? Does `theme(text=element_text(size=10))` doesn't apply to labels?

And why size of 10 in `geom_text()` is different from that in `theme(text=element_text())` ?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Here are a few options for changing text / label sizes

```
library(ggplot2)

# Example data using mtcars

a <- aggregate(mpg ~ vs + am , mtcars, function(i) round(mean(i)))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), y=mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
            geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
            geom_text(data = a, aes(label = mpg), 
                            position = position_dodge(width=0.9),  size=20)
```

The `size` in the `geom_text` changes the size of the `geom_text` labels.

```
p <- p + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15)) # changes axis labels

p <- p + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 25)) # change axis titles

p <- p + theme(text = element_text(size = 10)) # this will change all text size 
                                                             # (except geom_text)
```

For this *And why size of 10 in geom_text() is different from that in theme(text=element_text()) ?*

Yes, they are different. I did a quick manual check and they appear to be in the ratio of ~ (14/5) for `geom_text` sizes to `theme` sizes.

So a horrible fix for uniform sizes is to scale by this ratio

```
geom.text.size = 7
theme.size = (14/5) * geom.text.size

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), y=mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  geom_text(data = a, aes(label = mpg), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9),  size=geom.text.size) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = theme.size, colour="black"))
```

This of course doesn't explain *why?* and is a pita (and i assume there is a more sensible way to do this)

Comment: interesting, what did you check to find out the 14/5 ratio ?

Comment: i see. you remind me of something I read recently, I guess it's the difference in units, geom_text default of 5 might be 5mm and the theme() size unit is point. 1 point is 1/72 inch=0.35mm, so 1 in geom_text() is 1mm, 1/0.35 =~ 14/5 :)

Comment: agstudy's answer describes the why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size

Comment: And for those of us who want to go the other way, and convert `geom_text` to "regular" font size, you can just **multiply by 0.36.**

Answer (score 13):

I had this question, and found on the [aesthetic specifications ggplot help page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#text) that they add in a handy function for converting mm (default for geom_text for consistency with lines and point) to points (the scale for theme)- you simply put in your font size (in pt), then type /.pt.

So your code would be:

```
ggplot(data=file,aes(x=V1,y=V3,fill=V2)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge",colour="white") + 
geom_text(aes(label=V2),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
          hjust=1.5,colour="white", size = 10/.pt) +
theme_bw()
```

This conversion does the equivalent of what Nova mentioned above. Hope this is helpful for anyone looking for this answer in the future.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2023. Use the built-in helper function  `.pt` to divide your pt-input by.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the relevant entry in ggplot2's customization FAQ: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/faq-customising.html#what-is-the-default-size-of-geom_text-and-how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-geom_text

You can modify the default size of `geom_text()` by placing `update_geom_defaults("text", list(size = X)`, where X is your choice of new size, at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062509/2227743):

Look up `?.pt` and you will understand what 14/5 means and why it is needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35301737)