# What is the default unit of annotate() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I've been looking what seems to be everywhere. I would like to know what the default unit size of annotate() is in ggplot2, as I'm not able to set size to a specific unit in annotate().

For example, I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
annotate(geom = "text", label = "Am I a bird?",
           x = "ABC", y = 2375/2,
           family = "Arial", size = unit(10, "mm"), colour = "white")

Error in checkNA("fontsize") : 
  mixture of missing and non-missing values for fontsize
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The size of text is measured in mm. Simply using `size = 10` therefore results in a font size of 10mm. If you want want to draw a 10pt text instead, set size = 10 / ggplot2::.pt. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#text.

Comment: funnily, this is a constant. To convert to your desired pt, factorise your annotate font size by 5/14

Comment: That worked perfectly, @Tjebo ! Thanks a lot. How did you know it was exactly that factor? Is there an online resource somewhere?

Comment: I saw it a couple of years ago somewhere. One of those things...  The online resource is actually provided by @IanCampbell in their answer - 14/5 is roughly the same.

Comment: here we go - I think this was the thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061822/ggplot-geom-text-font-size-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says [here](https://ggplot2-book.org/annotations.html) that the default unit is mm. So if you want to go from points to mm multiply by `72.27 / 25.4`.