# ggplot how to control fonts on boxplot with stat

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How do I control the font-family and size for text elements added to my boxplot:

Following the approach [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846348/add-number-of-observations-per-group-in-ggplot2-boxplot), I have implemented the following code **to show the number of observations**:

```
library("ggplot2")

v_min <- -1
v_max <- 3.5
increm <- 0.5
y_limits <- c(v_min, v_max)
increms <- seq(v_min, v_max, increm)


counts <- function(x){
  # you can experiment with 'adjust' and 'max-value' to find the perfect position
  adjust <- 0.95
  return(c(y = adjust * v_max, label = length(x))) 
  
}

ggplot(d1, aes(x = ONRC_Hierarchy, y=lwpMeanRut_inc)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.2, outlier.size = 0.5) + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), color="blue", linetype="dotted", size=1)+
    stat_summary(fun.data = counts, geom = "text") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = y_limits, breaks = increms) + 
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Rut Increment (mm/year)\n") + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(
          text = element_text(size = 10, family = "mono"),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -35, hjust = 0),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "lightgray",
                                        size = 0.15,linetype = 2),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

This solution works, as shown in the plot below, **except that the font is different from the other graph elements**. As you can see, I have tried to control this with the theme() statement, but it does not seem to work. Note, I deliberately used a small mono font to show the difference in the number of observations labels and the other graph elements.

[image]

Comment: geom fonts aren't in theme, you set them in the layer directly. Add `family = "mono"` as an argument to your `stat_summary()`

Comment: @GregorThomas - thanks! that worked. I modified it like this: stat_summary(fun.data = counts, geom = "text", family = "mono", size = 3). Size seems to mean something different here compared to when it is used in theme(). Do you want to add your comment as an answer? Then I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geom/stat fonts are set in the geom/stat layer, not in `theme()`. In this case, you can add `family = "mono"` as an argument to your `stat_summary()`.

The size of fonts in `geom_text`/`geom_label` etc. is not on the same scale as `element_text` theme options, which are in points. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061822/ggplot-geom-text-font-size-control) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size).