# ggsave does not constrain line width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour=factor(gear))) + 
  facet_wrap(~am) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  theme(
    axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
    axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid")
  )

ggsave(filename = "~/Desktop/test.pdf")
```

In the docs of the `element_line()` function it is not specified which unit the `size` attribute has. But when I open the produced pdf in Illustrator the axis lines are shown as 1.07 pt lines.

So... what is the unit of the `size` attribute and how can I achieve that the output has a line width of 0.5 pt?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size

Comment: Not specifically, but I already had the idea that it might be a conversion between points and mm. There the factor is 0.35 or 2.83 depending on the direction of conversion. But here the factor is 2.14 (R -> AI) or 0.47 (AI -> R). So, that doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion factor is (72.27/25.4)*(72.27/96)=2.141959. So, as you note, `size=0.5` results in a line that is 1.07pt wide. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47521808/4975218) for details.