# What is the best way to define point size for a package using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, internals, units-of-measurement

In ggplot2, font size is based on a constant for converting points, inches, and mm: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/geom-.r line 193, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312440/8400969). I apparently need to reference the `ggplot2:::.pt` constant in a package, where it is frowned upon to include internal functions from other package. How should I do this to minimize headaches for myself, users, and ggplot2 auhtors/maintainers? For example, I could copy the ggplot2 source code in my package (seems allowed by MIT license), ask the ggplot2 authors to export the `graphical_units` objects, or I could paraphrase... Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I created a file called utils-graphical_units.R in my package and copied the ggplot2 source for the time being.

Comment: `.pt` is exported, it is not internal, so just use `ggplot2::.pt`

Comment: D'oh! You'd think I would have noticed when I copied the functions! Thanks!

Comment: The constants won't change, so couldn't you just hard code the ratio? 72.27 comes from the definition of one TeX point, which is 1/72.27 of an inch, and 25.4   is mm : inch conversion. So defining `.pt <- 72.27 / 25.4` will not require any ongoing maintenance...
   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pt` (and `.stroke`) are already exported graphical units from `ggplot2` so can be imported into your package using the standard `ggplot2::.pt` or `@importFrom ggplot2 .pt`.

Comment: I definitely prefer using the exported constant to hard-coding, since it releases me from fully documenting this bizarre-looking number or ratio. I'm trying to troubleshoot how ggplot is interacting with device sizes, so keeping all the `ggplot2` code together is helpful for me for now, and possibly for a downstream user.

Comment: The `.pt` constant is just a conversion constant from points to millimeters. You could use `grid::convertUnit(grid::unit(1, "mm"), "pt", valueOnly = TRUE)` to reconstruct it.